# AWS Lambda with Go: "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint" Error for POST Request to API Gateway Endpoint

Tags: go, aws-lambda, makefile, aws-cdk

I'm building an AWS Lambda function in Go that should be triggered via an API Gateway endpoint. I'm facing an issue where invoking the endpoint through a POST request results in a 502 error. I've set up my project based on a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/KyDWCyDqMLE), but something seems to be off.

To compile my Go functions programmatically, I'm using a Makefile to generate a `main` executable in each function's directory. Here's the `build` section of my `Makefile`:

```
build:
    @echo "Building functions..."
    @$(foreach func, $(FUNCTIONS), \
        go build -o $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/$(BINARY_NAME) $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/main.go && \
        echo "Built $(func)/$(BINARY_NAME)"; \
    )

# Deploy stack with AWS CDK
.PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    echo "Deploying stack..."
    cdk deploy --profile $(AWS_PROFILE)
```

I deploy my stack with the command `make deploy`.

The relevant part of my `love-go-serverless-stack.ts` file looks like this:

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { RestApi, LambdaIntegration } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';

export class LoveGoServerlessStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Hello Lambda function
    const helloFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'HelloFunction', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/functions/hello'),
      handler: 'main',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PROVIDED_AL2023,
    });

    // The API Gateway
    const gateway = new RestApi(this, 'MyGateway', {
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowOrigins: ['*'],
        allowMethods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      },
    });

    // The Lambda integration
    const integration = new LambdaIntegration(helloFunction);

    // Creating the '/hello' resource
    const helloResource = gateway.root.addResource('hello');
    helloResource.addMethod('POST', integration); // POST method for the 'hello' resource
  }
}
```

When I make a POST request to the CloudFront URL provided by API Gateway, I receive a 502 error. The CloudWatch logs indicate a recurring error related to the Lambda function's entry point:

```
RequestId: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

And:

```
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 0.27 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

I'm puzzled by the "invalid entrypoint" error, as I have configured the `/hello` route in my CDK stack (`love-go-serverless-stack.ts`). Could this be related to how the Go binary is named or packaged? Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

[The repository for the code](https://github.com/kstcovflw/love-go-serverless)

##### My environment:

- Windows 11
- go 1.21.5
- node 18.18.2

[image]

---

#### Update

- I was able to run `make build` after switching to Mac and fixing indentation inside Makefile. I still have trouble running my code on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Blog Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-go1-x-runtime-to-the-custom-runtime-on-amazon-linux-2/), migrating your Lambda function from the `GO_1_X` environment to the `PROVIDED_AL2023` environment requires renaming the executable file to a generic `bootstrap` name. This modification necessitates changes to your build script. Additionally, I compressed the binary into a ZIP file to create a deployment package, making it ready for Lambda deployment.

```
build:
  @echo "Building functions..."
  @$(foreach func, $(FUNCTIONS), \
      go build -o $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/bootstrap $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/main.go && \
      cd $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func); zip ../$(func).zip bootstrap \
      echo "Built $(func)/$(BINARY_NAME)"; \
  )

# Deploy stack with AWS CDK
.PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    echo "Deploying stack..."
    cdk deploy --profile $(AWS_PROFILE)
```

This will create zip packages in the $(FUNCTIONS_DIR) folder, allowing you to modify how you create a lambda function in your CDK project. Note that the handler must be renamed to `bootstrap`.

```
const helloFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'HelloFunction', {
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, `../../bin/${func}.zip`)),,
    handler: 'bootstrap',
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.PROVIDED_AL2023,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I tried applying your suggestion, but I'm still encountering an issue with the Makefile. Specifically, I'm getting a "missing separator" error when I run the `make build` command. Did you try creating a .zip file based on my repository, and if so, were you successful?

Comment: @kawa Sorry, I think it was a missing separator "\" there in the makefile. I fixed the script. I've tried it and it worked out well (after the fix).

Comment: Thank you for your help! After taking a closer look at the code, I realized the issue was due to incorrect indentation. I managed to run the code successfully on my Mac, but I'm still working on getting it to run on Windows. ( I get error when I run the same Makefile on Windows for some reason. )